# what does this command do: pip install -e <some text>

Tags: pip

What does this command do?

pip install -e ".[gpu]"

I've seen some documentation on the -e option, but I'm confused by the text afterwards.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+%22-e%22

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+square+brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `[gpu]` is the name of the requirements group from `setup.py`. take a look at [this](https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/dependency_management.html) for more information.

[pip install -e](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#install-editable) is how setuptools dependencies are handled via `pip`

Comment: Thank you for the explanation and link!